# Button OnClicklistener from dynamically genereated Buttons

Tags: android, json, android-layout, button, onclicklistener

I have a problem to build correct OnClicklistener for buttons I generate at runtime. I found some threads here on stackoverflow but after many tries I don't get it working.

I have a methode with builds a GUI with a TextView in left "column" and in right "column" x buttons. Each Button has an other link which should be open by onClick. I don't know the link before it's created at runtime.

Here my Code with my actuall try. But in this Case I get everytime only the link of the last generated button. If I click on first one, second one .... it's everytime the same link.

Hope there is a solution for it!

```
  private void createNewView (String JsonInputBeacon, String JsonInputConfig){

    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);

    try {
        final JSONArray jsonArrayBeacon = new JSONArray(JsonInputBeacon);
        final JSONArray jsonArrayConfig = new JSONArray(JsonInputConfig);


        int Patientencounter = 1;

        for(int JsonObjectCounterBeacon = 0; JsonObjectCounterBeacon < jsonArrayBeacon.length(); JsonObjectCounterBeacon ++ ){
            final JSONObject objectBeacon = jsonArrayBeacon.getJSONObject(JsonObjectCounterBeacon);

            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            TextView outputLeft = new TextView(this);
            outputLeft.setText("Patient " + Patientencounter + ":\n" + "Name: " + objectBeacon.getString("surname") + ", " + objectBeacon.getString("firstName") + "\n" + "Geb-Datum: " + objectBeacon.getString("birthdate"));

            row.addView(outputLeft);

            for (int JsonObjectCounterConfig = 0; JsonObjectCounterConfig < jsonArrayConfig.length(); JsonObjectCounterConfig++){
                final JSONObject objectConfig = jsonArrayConfig.getJSONObject(JsonObjectCounterConfig);

                TableRow rowRight = new TableRow(this);
                Button buttonRight = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                buttonRight.setText(objectConfig.getString("name"));
                final String myURL = objectConfig.getString("link");

                buttonRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(myURL));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                    }
                });

                rowRight.addView(buttonRight);
                row.addView(rowRight);
            }

            tableLayout.addView(row);

            Patientencounter +=1;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setContentView(tableLayout);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in this Case I get everytime only the link of the last generated
>   button. If I click on first one, second one .... it's everytime the
>   same link

Because `myURL`contains value which is assigned by last iteration of `for-loop`.

Use `setTag/getTag` method of  `buttonRight` to get url according to `Button` click. like:

Set value using `setTag` :

```
final String myURL = objectConfig.getString("link");
buttonRight.setTag(myURL);
```

and get `myURL` value using `v` parameter of `onClick` method:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                 Uri.parse(v.getTag().toString()));
```

Comment: Thats the solution. It works fine!!!

Thanks for fast reply! I tried it since hours...

Answer (score 0):

Set the tag of your button to be the URI, then access the tag from the view passed in to your onclick method.